# Android ViewModel/MutableLiveData onChanged gets called in a new fragment when data has not changed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I am running into a problem with Android Mutable Live Data and it might be because of my poor understanding. The scenario is I have 3 lists in my Android tabs.

```
public void openSort(SortType sortType) {
    mSortType.postValue(sortType);
}

public MutableLiveData<SortType> getOpenSort() {
    return mSortType;
}
```

In my activity I have my first fragment open. In that I call the

> public void openSort(SortType sortType)

Everything works fine so far. Then I go ahead and open another tab which has the second fragment. This second fragment in its

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     SortOrderViewModel sortOrderViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SortOrder.class);
     sortOrderViewModel.observe(this, new Observer() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(SortType sortType) {
                 // Debug print
            }
     })
}
```

For some reason the onChanged of the second fragment gets called too. My assumption was that the onChanged method only gets called when the data changes in the view model, but it seems the data is stored by the LiveData and the observers are notified again.

Is there something that we can do such that the fragment is "only" notified when the mutable live data has changed?

Comment: Why is it that you do not want the second fragment to receive the current data right away? That is the expected behavior, since usually you set up a binding between the data and your UI and this means that the UI should show the current data right away.

Comment: As soon as I start the second fragment, the sort activity opens up which I do not want.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. LiveData and the observers are usually used to bind the view to the current data: Whenever new data is available, you want to update your view according to these changes. That is the reason you receive an onChanged() event ride away after setting up the observer - so the UI can update to the current data.
Instead apparently you use the onChange() for some kind of navigation event, so you start an activity within it. If you want to use LiveData for navigation event, read here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/63

Comment: This is where arch components go to far.  Do not auto post things for me unless I have requested it.  This might make them basically worthless for me.  I have been working on an example where my view and logic where completely separate, and more testable . Because of this auto post behavior, I'm getting view events triggered even though nothing has been request and no values have changed, so I'll have to hold state in my view, so I can know to ignore unwanted posting of events.